# Android, Doing the AnimationDrawable from the docs... not working :(

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to get this example working:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

but as it starts, it crashes (force closes) and I am not really sure where the problem is as I am new to this.

My code:
(Java file)

```
package com.ryan.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TestAnimationActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);            

        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);
        img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);    
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();    
        frameAnimation.start();            
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Animation XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/note0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/note1" android:duration="50" />        
 </animation-list>
```

Main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/note0"
        android:id="@+id/spinning_wheel_image"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that the animation xml file is in res/drawable-hdpi, putting it in the res/anim folder was giving me errors. Also note I am an Android noobie ;)

Thanks!
Ryan

EDIT;

There IS a bug in the demo code: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1818
so i modified the code: pastebin.com/ZtLf8J87
and it works ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation xml should always decide in res/anim. The reason it is throwing an error is due to the fact that you are using ImageView img =

> (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.spinning_wheel_image);

before setting the content view i.e

> setContentView(R.layout.main);

For tracking the errors and debugging use Logcat.You may find that in Eclipse at following location. Windows => Open Perspective => Logcat

Comment: Ok, did what you said and I am getting the error "spin_animation cannot be resolved or is not a field" in the java file at "img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);"

Comment: you sure that there is a drawable spin_animation in the res/drawable folder?

Comment: I think so, here's the way it looks: http://free-image-host.ezee.se/pic.php?p=12709110_capture2.jpg

Comment: i could not see that in the drawable  folder. i could only find icon and note1-note9 in drawable-hdpi.

Comment: You wrote that "The animation xml should always decide in res/anim." so I moved it to res/anim, you want me to move it back?

Comment: No. animation xml should decide in res/anim. Apart from this the drawable spin_animation should be added to the res/drawable folder. This drawable is referred here =>img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spin_animation);   which is not seen in the drawable folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3810/discussion-between-khotmanish-and-ryan)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, i've awarded you the solution.